# json reading issue array without title

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, url

I have a JSON array that does not have a title.

I keep trying to read the JSON through but it seems to keep failing.
I am hoping there is some kind of example of parsing JSON without calling the array name.

Any help or pointing me in the direction of an example would be greatly appreciated. I will attach the code that I am having errors with below. The two urls are of the data I am attempting to read in.

https://www.descartes.com/rest/glossary-items
https://www.descartes.com/rest/glossary-sources

**JsonParser:**

```
public class JsonParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jarray = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url1) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url1);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
            // System.out.println(""+jarray);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jarray;

    }
}
```

**doInBackground:**

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String str = "";
    JsonParser sh = new JsonParser();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.getJSONFromUrl(url1, JsonParser.GET);

    if (jsonStr != null){
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonArr);
            test = jsonArr.getJSONObje(str);
            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = str.getJSONObject(i);

                String tid = c.getString(TAG_TID);
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String acronym = c.getString(TAG_ACRONYM);
                String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);


                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_TID, tid);
                contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                contact.put(TAG_ACRONYM, acronym);
                contact.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                // adding contact to contact list
                glossaryList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("JsonParser", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: paste an example of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

2-nd: you have typos in your code for example: `test = jsonArr.getJSONObje(str);` there is no such method in JsonArray

3-d: you iterate over string for some reason:  `for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {`

So here is working demo code that you can upgrade for your needs:

```
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url1) {

    String responseBody = "";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url1);
    try {
        responseBody = client.execute(httpGet, new BasicResponseHandler());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(responseBody);
        return jarray;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return null;

}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    JsonParser sh = new JsonParser();
    JSONArray jsonArr = sh.getJSONFromUrl("https://www.descartes.com/rest/glossary-items");

    // looping through All Contacts
    if (jsonArr!= null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject contact =  jsonArr.optJSONObject(i);
            if (contact!= null)
                Log.e("jsonArr " + i + ":", contact.toString());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```